# file-transfer incidence in IOS IONIC 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, file-transfer, ionic-native

I commented that I am developing an application in IONIC 3 and I am working with the native file transfer library.

At the moment of wanting to download a file in IOS it does not execute it, not so when it is installed or debugged in android.

According to the ionic documentation I am implementing it correctly and I do not understand why or what is missing so that IOS can execute the `transfer.download` which is the instruction that is not executed

and I get the following error in the console:

> console.warn: 'Native: tried accessing the FileTransfer plugin but it's not installed.

Below I leave my code:

```
import { FileTransfer, FileTransferObject } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';

import { LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';

declare var cordova: any;

@IonicPage()
@Component({
selector: 'page-liquidaciones',
templateUrl: 'liquidaciones.html',
})
export class LiquidacionesPage {
formLiquidaciones: FormGroup;
 public txtCorreoLiquidacion;
rutUsuario: any;
resultado: any;
liquidaciones: any;
liquidacionesSeleccionadas:any={};
loading: any;
storageDirectory: string = '';
//private fileTransfer: FileTransferObject;
//private localPath = '';

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
          public navParams: NavParams,
          private alertCtrl: AlertController, 
          public formBuilder: FormBuilder, 
          public kiberKiberpro: KibernumKiberproProvider,
          public databaseService: DatabaseServiceProvider, 
          private transfer: FileTransfer, 
          private file: File,
          private androidPermissions: AndroidPermissions,
          public loadingController: LoadingController,
          public platform: Platform
        ){

this.formLiquidaciones = this.formBuilder.group({
  txtCorreoLiquidacion: ['', Validators.required]
});


this.platform.ready().then(() => {

  if(!this.platform.is('cordova')) {
    return false;
  }

  if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
    //this.storageDirectory = this.file.dataDirectory;
    this.storageDirectory = cordova.file.dataDirectory;
  }
  else if(this.platform.is('android')) {
    this.storageDirectory = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + '/Download/';
    this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE).then(
      result => {
        if (result.hasPermission) {
          // code
        } else {
          this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE).then(result => {
            if (result.hasPermission) {
              // code
            }
          });
        }
      },
      err => this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    );

  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
});

  this.databaseService.getSesion(2).then(result => {
    this.rutUsuario = result.valor;
    })
  .catch( error => {
  });
}

DescargarLiquidaciones(){
this.loading = this.loadingController.create({ content: "Descargando Liquidacion(es)..." });
  const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();

  var enviarLiquidaciones = [];
  for(var i in this.liquidacionesSeleccionadas) {
    if(this.liquidacionesSeleccionadas[i]) {
      enviarLiquidaciones.push(i);
    }
  }

  if(enviarLiquidaciones.length == 0)
  {
    this.alerta("Debe seleccionar por lo menos una liquidación para que sea descargada.");
  }
  else
  {
    this.loading.present();

    this.txtCorreoLiquidacion = '';
    this.kiberKiberpro.DescargarEnviarLiquidaciones(this.rutUsuario,enviarLiquidaciones, this.txtCorreoLiquidacion).then((res) => {
      this.resultado = res;
      var respuesta = JSON.parse(this.resultado.data);
      let datos: string = JWT(this.resultado.data);
      if(respuesta.status == "200") {
        let autorizacion = this.resultado.headers;
        let nombreArchivo = datos.split("tmp/");
        let urlFinal = datos;
        fileTransfer.download(urlFinal , this.storageDirectory  + nombreArchivo[1]).then((entry) => {  
          console.log("LLEGA ACA");
          this.alerta("Se ha descargado el archivo de manera satisfactoria.");
          console.log("LLEGA ACA 2");
          this.loading.dismissAll();
          console.log("LLEGA ACA 3");
          this.databaseService.GuardaSQLlite(1, autorizacion.authorization);
          this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
        }, (error) => {
          this.alerta("Hubo un error al momento de descargar el archivo. Si el problema persiste favor contactarse al 816 35 12 o 816 35 09.");
          this.loading.dismissAll();
        });

      }
      else if (respuesta.status == "201"){
        this.alerta("Hubo un problema con el envío de la(s) liquidacion(es) al correo ingresado. Si el problema persiste favor contactarse al 816 35 12 o 816 35 09");
        this.loading.dismissAll();
        let autorizacion = this.resultado.headers;
        this.databaseService.GuardaSQLlite(1, autorizacion.authorization);
      }
      else if (respuesta.status == "401"){
        this.alerta("Token no válido.");
        this.loading.dismissAll();
      }
      else{
        this.alerta("Hubo un problema inesperado, Favor intente nuevamente. Si el problema persiste favor contactarse al 816 35 12 o 816 35 09");
        this.loading.dismissAll();
      }
    }, (err) => {
      this.alerta("Ha ocurrido un problema, intente nuevamente por favor. Si el error persiste pongase en contacto con el area de soporte.");
      this.loading.dismissAll();
    });
  }
}
```

I remain attentive to your answers and I thank you in advance for your help and opinions

Comment: Are you running the Android and iOS tests on different machines?  If so, seems like you need to run `npm install` on the iOS machine?

Comment: First of all thank you for responding. answering your question is yes, I'm actually running Android and IOS on different computers. with respect to the npm install, I have already done so since I downloaded the sources from scratch from the repository available by the company on github. In fact, if I did not have the npm plugin installed, it would claim me when I wanted to build or run ios, which is not the case

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to put the information of my ionic which is the following:

Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.1.2 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.10

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.1 (cordova-lib@8.1.0)
   Cordova Platforms     : ios 4.5.4
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 6 other plugins)

System:

ios-deploy : 2.0.0
   NodeJS     : v8.12.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.4.1
   OS         : macOS
   Xcode      : Xcode 9.4 Build version 9F1027a

Comment: no need to post it as an answer, you can edit the initial question

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your file transfer logic is not wrapped in a `this.platform.ready()` call.  Could it be that there are times when this is called before platform ready (and thus, before the plugin is ready to be used)?